# segmentation fault doesnot give core file

Tags: c, linux, pthreads

```
OS : centos 5
ldd --version
ldd (GNU libc) 2.5
```

I have a binary with multiple threads,

in /var/log/messages

```
Mar 25 10:57:46 1427261266 kernel: skeen[21480]: segfault at 48 ip b7706ac0 sp bfc2e448 error 4 in libpthread-2.5.so[b76fc000+15000]
```

setting is :

```
[root@manage ~]# ulimit -a
core file size          (blocks, -c) 1000000
data seg size           (kbytes, -d) unlimited
scheduling priority             (-e) 0
file size               (blocks, -f) unlimited
pending signals                 (-i) 15931
max locked memory       (kbytes, -l) 64
max memory size         (kbytes, -m) unlimited
open files                      (-n) 1024
pipe size            (512 bytes, -p) 8
POSIX message queues     (bytes, -q) 819200
real-time priority              (-r) 0
stack size              (kbytes, -s) 8192
cpu time               (seconds, -t) unlimited
max user processes              (-u) 15931
virtual memory          (kbytes, -v) unlimited
file locks                      (-x) unlimited
[root@manage ~]# cat /proc/sys/kernel/core_pattern
    /var/cores/core.%e.%p.%h.%t
```

But still I couldn't get any "core" file in /var/cores location.
Further my binary is still running.What above line actually showing ? any why is not any core file generated ?

Comment: What does ulimit -a say?

Comment: You may want to look at `man 5 core` and its references, as well.

Comment: Please find ulimit -a output at the question

Comment: I can generate other core files at the same location.

Comment: `suid` binaries will refuse to dump core for security reasons.

Comment: ll /usr/sbin/skeen
-rwxr-xr-x    1 root     root      2078174 Oct 15  2013 /usr/sbin/skeen